# EF code Model for e-tender system in MVC4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, model

Am building tender board Application am getting some confusing in how structure my model using >> entity-framework in >> MVC4

Here the descriptions:
In my simple membership Role Table , I have: 
**(Admin,Tender,Provider,Member)**

**Administration:** he have right to change normal user role from “Member” to “Provider and prove winner bidder after tender organization approved.

**Suppliers:** Normal users will be assigning as “member” and will be activated by Administration to be provider and then they can bid any projects they want.

**Projects:** created by Tender Organization Users every project has many requirements

**Requirement:** each one related to project.

**Tenders**: Here my problem actually Tender are “Ministries in country and have to be set in system” but each ministry obvious have many users “Manager, let say 5 in each” who will vote for supplier.Mangers can vote to only those suppliers which are laid under the same ministry.

**Do I miss others tables?**

**Also** I don’t really know how to structure all the tables with relations and also with (UserprofileTbale, and Role Table):
Here my try, help me on that.

*My DBContext:*

```
 public class ProjectContext : DbContext
{
    public ProjectContext()
        : base("OTMSProjects")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ProjectEntry> Entries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Requiernments> RequiernmentEntries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tender> Tenders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    //public DbSet<UserRoles> UserRoles { get; set; } // do I have to set this too?
}}
```

My tables:

```
     public class ProjectEntry
   {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Statue {get; set; }
    public string UplodedFiles { get; set; }
    public string Budget { get; set; }
    public string EstimateTime { get; set; }
    public string Criterias { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }


    // Relations  with others tables

    public virtual Tender Tender { get; set; }// every  project have only one tender
    public virtual ICollection<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; } // every  project have one or more  supplier 
    public virtual ICollection<Requiernments> Requirements { get; set; }

}
```

........

```
   public class Requiernments
    {
                            [Key]
                            public int RequiernmentId { get; set; }
                            public int ID { get; set; }

                            public string RequiernmentName { get; set; }

                            public string RequiernmentType { get; set; }

                            public string RequiernmentPrioritet { get; set; }

                            public float RequiernmenWhight { get; set; }
                            public string ProviderAnswer { get; set; }
                            public string ProviderComments{ get; set; }
                            public virtual ProjectEntry Projects { get; set; } 


}
```

........

```
 public class Supplier
   {
    [Key]
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SupplierName { get; set; }
    public int SupplierCat { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProjectEntry> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

......

```
  public class Tender
   {
    [Key]

    public int TenderId { get; set; }
    public string TenderName { get; set; }
    public string TenderMinstry{ get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }//link to project 
    public int UserId { get; set; }  //this links to the userid in the UserProfiles table
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectEntry> Projects { get; set; }
    //public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> Userprofile { get; set; } 
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

My membership table in my AccountModel created by defualt in Mvc4 ( I only add the RoleTable :

```
  [Table("UserProfile")]
  public class UserProfile
  {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserRoles> UserRoles { get; set; }

}

   [Table("webpages_Roles")]
   public class UserRoles
  {
    [Key]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
   }
```

**Am not sure also about how to link the Userprofile with Tender Table and supplier Table?**

Comment: "Do I miss others tables?", is that your question? StackOverflow is not the right place for design questions.

Comment: No , I need to check the relations between tables (one to many ) and (many to many )

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are missed or not. but as per database creation you must follow your business logic and normalization rules.

Some of my suggestions are here:
1.  ProjectEntry
here you should create a Status Table separately and gives its reference key as StatusID into the ProjectEntry table.

1. Requirement
   you should create Requirement Priority and Type tables are separately.
   Add separate table for provider question and answers. I hope you need to store more than one question answers for single requirement.
2. Supplier
   Add Separate Table for Supplier category
3. Tender
   Create Tender Ministry table separately and give its reference to the tender table.
4. you should make a table for Uploaded files as Documents. It should contains ID, ProjectId, Documentname, DocumentType, DocumentShortDescription, uplodatedDateTime fields.

Comment: Goods points thank you ..?is  relations between tables correct?

Comment: also am not sure how to link the UserProfile with Tender and supplier !

Comment: Can you tell what types of users, I mean, Roles are there? Or contact me on my email so we can do a long discussion over there. you can fine my contact detail on my profile.

Comment: (Admin,Tender,Provider,Member)

Comment: Here you should make 3 tables,
1. Users (UserID, etc...)
2. Roles (RoleID, RoleName)
3. UserRoles (UserId, RoleID)
This will be fulfill your requirements.
Let me know if any confusion at your side.

Comment: yah I have them see my Questions

Comment: Tender are “Ministries in country and have to be set in system” but each ministry obvious have many users “Manager, let say 5 in each” who will vote for supplier.

Comment: But you tell, what is your business logic? is any manger can vote for any supplier. or only mangers can vote to only those suppliers which are laid under the same ministry?  
First tell what is your business.?? what is your requirement??

Comment: manger"I call them tenderUser" can vote to only those suppliers which are laid under the same ministry.

Comment: Then Add a table for SupplierMinistryRelation(ID, MinistryID, SupplierID) and ManagerMinistryRelation(ID, MinistryID, UserID) here only those userID are stored which role is manger. And give permission to vote up to supplier only those users which are into the same ministry and found into the MangerMinistryRelation table.